# Generate model for different results of stored procedure in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My stored procedure is giving me different columns depending upon parameters used. How can I generate model for all results of stored procedure in Entity Framework?

Comment: Have you tried using Function import and generate complex types for result/returned value?

Comment: IIRC, ef doesn't like sp's that return dynamic results.  you will have to create some complex types on the ef model, then import and wire up the functions manually.  You may need to create a generic function that will be bind the result to that type, either way, something is going to need to know up front what is being returned for each param set.

Comment: Yes I have tried it but Function import and generate complex types in designer do not ask for SP parameters

Comment: That's a **really horribly bad idea** - a stored procedure should not change it's result shape based on input parameters - makes it impossible to use it in EF  and really hard to use anywhere else. If you have to have different result set shapes, then use separate stored procedure - one per shape

Comment: I know but the stored procedure is written by DBA in my company that I cant change.